# Defining automatic sequences on maple

Tags: maple

I am using maple to investigate some properties or numerical experiments to see a automatic sequences satisfy certain properties.

First, I would like to define the following sequence on maple. The nth term of the sequence is given by the following expression `i_{n}=(-1)^{inv_2(n)}`, where inv_2(n) denotes the occurrences of 10 as a scattered subsequence in the binary representation of a number n. For example `2=0x2^{0}+1x2^{1}+0...` so the binary representation of 2 is 10, the inversion is therefore 1 and so the above expression I talked about take the value of -1, a more general example will be the binary representation of 12 is 1100, then the `inv_2(12)` in this case is 4 as we count 10 as a scattered subsequence.

How can I  define such a sequence on maple?

Comment: I'm sure that it's possible in Maple, but you need to give more examples of inv_2(n). What is inv_2(1010)? inv_2(11100)? inv_2(1001)?

Comment: Please see the reply below Carl :) i hope it clarifies

Comment: Hello Carl,if 1010 is already the binary representation of certain number n, then inv_2 in this case would be 3. For 11100 inv_2 would be 6. And inv_2 1001 would be 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've interpretted your examples correctly, then this is the procedure **inv_2**:

```
inv_2:= proc(n::nonnegint)
local N:= convert(n, base, 2), L:= nops(N), i, j, ct:= 0;
     for i from L by -1 to 1 do
          if N[i] = 1 then
               for j from i-1 by -1 to 1 do
                    if N[j] = 0 then  ct:= ct+1  end if
               end do
          end if
     end do;
     ct
end proc:
```

Please confirm that this gives the correct results.

Comment: Well, it's been two days now. Does my procedure satisfy your needs or not?!

Comment: Hello Carl, thank you very much for your answer! It works indeed. I am wondering if I can ask you the following question under this post as well if you can possibly help.

Comment: I don't see the following question.

Comment: Hello Carl, sorry for the late reply. I am looking at the following map that sends A to AB, B to CA, C to BD and D to DC. I know how to define it on maple. And say if I iterate AB then I will have an infinite word, then I want to do the following procedure by assigning A, B to +1 and C,D to -1, how can I do that? Also once I define that I will have a sequence of +1 and -1, how can I then define it as a sequence if you know what I mean?

Comment: This is way too complicated for a comment. Please post a new Question and show the Maple code that you already have.